# How to find the complex part of the complex analytic function whose real part is given?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Consider the real function of two real variables given by $$u(x, y)=e^{2x}[\sin 3x\cos 2y\cosh 3y-\cos 3x\sin 2y\sinh 3y].$$
Let $v(x, y)$ be the harmonic conjugate of $u(x, y)$ such that $v(0, 0) = 2$. Let $z = x+iy$
and $f(z) = u(x, y) + iv(x, y)$, then find the value of $4 + 2if (i\pi)$.

I know that $v(x, y)$ can be calculated by solving the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Is there any short method for this problem apart from above?

Comment: Calculate the real part of $e^{(a+bi)z}$ It should be helpful. Then substitute $a=2$ and $b=\pm 3.$

Comment: I have verified, that the imaginary part is more convenient, or the real part of $-ie^{(a+bi)z}.$